# How do I login to Sphider?

Tags: search-engines

Has anyone else here used Sphider? I am able to install everything (exactly as instructed [here](http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php))and change the password, but unable to login at the login screen. Whenever I login, it just refreshes the page, whether the credentials are correct or not.

I have looked at the [forum](http://www.sphider.eu/forum/read.php?2,9596) and others have the same problem too, but no one has provided a solution. So if any of you have tried Sphider and had the same problem your input would be much appreciated.

Running version 1.3.6
Path to admin page is 'sphider-1.3.6/admin/admin.php'
PHP Version 5.3.13
MySQL Version 5.0.91-log

Comment: In case you don't receive an answer on this site, maybe you could email the author (Ando Saabas) at the bottom of the site, and post the answer here?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem using Sphider myself. In the end the only solution was to use Sphider Pro and manually access the database after installation and manually update the password to suit what I needed. Have not been able to find out what caused the original glitch but this is the only workaround I have been able to find that worked for me.